# What are the prerequisites to learning about Lie groupoids, Lie algebroids and holomorphic foliations?

Tags: lie-algebroids, lie-groupoids, holomorphic-foliations

I am a graduate student of Theoretical Physics and intend to take a course titled "Introduction to Lie groupoids, Lie algebroids and holomorphic foliations". The course page doesn't have information on the prerequisites. Thus, I would like to ask what are they. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest reading introductory notes or books like the ones shown below, though you shouldn't just read them passively. You should understand their concepts as well as possible to best prepare for the course.

Resources:

$1$: [Lecture notes on Lie Groupoids, Lie algebroids, and holomorphic foliations](http://www.math.toronto.edu/mein/teaching/MAT1341_LieGroupoids/Groupoids.pdf)

$2$: Introduction to Foliations and Lie Groupoids by I. Moerdijk and J. Mrčun.

$3$: [Sample of Introduction to Foliations and Lie Groupoids by I. Moerdijk and J. Mrčun](http://catdir.loc.gov/catdir/samples/cam041/2003046172.pdf)